# Action Filters + AspNetRedisProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, redis

Hi i am currently implementing this provider "https://github.com/kylesonaty/AspNetRedisProviders" for an application i am currently working on in asp.net mvc4. However things are not as rosy as i initially thought they would be. Since the providers are derived from respective abstract counterparts, I did like to know if the default authorize filters in asp.net mvc will still delegate calls to these providers

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The default Authorization filter would provide some hooks to the Roles established by your custom provider. It is not directly, but indirectly. For example, your role provider would set roles, and the Authorization attribute can be used to verify a particular role has been defined by the configured role provider.

```
 protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
 {
  if (httpContext == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
  IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
  return user.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
   && (this._usersSplit.Length <= 0 ||
     Enumerable.Contains<string>((IEnumerable<string>) this._usersSplit, user.Identity.Name, (IEqualityComparer<string>) StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
   && (this._rolesSplit.Length <= 0 || Enumerable.Any<string>((IEnumerable<string>) 
     this._rolesSplit, new Func<string, bool>(user.IsInRole)));
  }
```

> *this._rolesSplit, new Func(user.IsInRole)));*

For instance, the last line, this would check the role is valid for the current user, which has been set by the role provider.